# how to fix slow kmeans of opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, computer-science

i use kmeans() for project about bag of words and it is took a lot of time i mean if i have 600 image it took 40-50 mins.and i look source code and that part took most of time:

```
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )///very very slow part because N*K is huge
        {
            sample = data.ptr<float>(i);
            int k_best = 0;
            double min_dist = DBL_MAX;


            for( k = 0; k < K; k++ )
            {
                const float* center = centers.ptr<float>(k);
                double dist = normL2Sqr_(sample, center, dims);

                if( min_dist > dist )
                {
                    min_dist = dist;
                    k_best = k;
                }
            }


            compactness += min_dist;
            labels[i] = k_best;

        }
```

and i try but i cant manage to reduce that part ,is there way to make it more efficient it take 22-23 secs in loop and it cause long time to wait programs finish running like 40-50 mins and it cause i cant try other video sets or image sets in program.If there is better kmeans code at c++ that will help too and if there is way to reduce N(# of features) that will help too but K is dictionary size i cant reduce it. Thanks for helps from now.

Comment: [k-means is slow](http://www.recognition.mccme.ru/pub/papers/clustering/kMeans-socg.pdf) - there's not a lot you can do about that apart from throw more hardware at it.

Comment: Hi, from you discription i have no idea what "that bit" is in context. But if it is from the runtime to find the NN then you may with to try approximate kNN with the FLANN library, which is also shipped with opencv. http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/, http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The k-means implementation in OpenCV is very inefficient, and there are a number of tricks to improve performance that they do not sure. It would be considerable work to re-write it yourself.

The implementation in [VLfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/kmeans.html) offers better algorithms for k-means, but I don't know about the quality of the implementation.